# Published React Native Expo app to Play Store. Want to update with Flutter. How to handle signing?

Tags: flutter, react-native, expo, android-app-signing

I am new to mobile development. Few months ago I developed a mobile app for Android using React Native Expo and submitted it to the Google Play Store. Now I need to redevelop this app in Flutter. How can I update this app on Google Play? How does app signing work, and what do I need for it? Before Expo did app Signing for me. please help.

I searched only for the steps but no luck. I was expecting a proper guid for the process from React Native to Flutter app migration